# Reserve Bank of India monetary policy operating target

Tags: central-banking

The operating target of RBI monetary policy is to keep weighted average call money market rate close to the policy repo rate. How does this  target help RBI achieve its goal of price stability and growth? The reason I get was it helps in better policy transmission but couldn't understand how.